# Multiple jQuery image galleries on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use this jQuery gallery more than once on my page:
http://workshop.rs/2010/07/create-image-gallery-in-4-lines-of-jquery/

The first one works, the second is a no-go. 
http://www.lakecommunicators.com/apex/test/publicrelations.php

The galleries under the first two are done with JavaScript and I am trying to replace them with jQuery.

Please help me if you can.

The code is short so I hope this is a breeze for one of you gurus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your image galleries have the same id gallery which is not allowed in html and the same with the id thumbs, change the second one to gallery2 and thumbs2, etc. Make sure you update the javascript with the new id as well.

```
$('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){

    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));

    $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));

});

$('#thumbs2').delegate('img','click', function(){

    $('#largeImage2').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));

    $('#description2').html($(this).attr('alt'));

});
```

the html

```
                      <div id="gallery2">

                          <div id="thumbs2"> <img src="images/image_01_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" /> <img src="images/image_02_thumb.jpg" alt="2nd image description" /> <img src="images/image_03_thumb.jpg" alt="3rd image description" /> <img src="images/image_04_thumb.jpg" alt="4th image description" /> <img src="images/image_05_thumb.jpg" alt="5th image description" /> </div>

                          <div id="panel2"> <img id="largeImage2" src="images/image_01_large.jpg" />

                            <div id="description2">1st image description</div>

                          </div>

                        </div>

                      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had done 70% of what you suggested by instinct ... I was missing the 
    $('#thumbs2').delegate.....

Much appreciated friend!